# How to write (A and B) or (C and D) with RewriteCond in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I create the following logic:
**(A and B) or (C and D)**
with RewriteCond?

The documentation wasn't very clear here, so I'm hoping some experts might shine some light.

I looked at the following post:
[how to use "AND", "OR" for RewriteCond on Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922399/how-to-use-and-or-for-rewritecond-on-apache)
This one made it somewhat clear for the given examples, but I'm still a little stuck.

Take the following example. If I need (A and B) or (C and D), would this be correct? Or is it A and (B or C) and D?

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B [OR]
RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
```

Is the following (A and B and C) or D, or is it A and B and (C or D)?

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteCond C [OR]
RewriteCond D
```

Is the only way to solve it by splitting them up into multiple RewriteRules?

Comment: It's `A` AND `B` OR `C` AND `D` . Either B or C is optional in your first example. The second one is A and B and C or D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: All the code examples are *semi-pseudo-code*, unless otherwise stated.

---

It's an interesting question, however, how you actually implement something like this is really dependent on exactly what you are trying to achieve. There are several methods/techniques to get the job done.

You can't implement this logic literally as you have it in your example, ie. with 4 conditions: A, B, C and D. And using `OR` and (implied) *AND* flags. This is because conditions are processed in order top to bottom, `OR` has precedence over an implied *AND* and there is no syntax to *group* conditions together (other than splitting into separate rules).

> ```
> RewriteCond A
> RewriteCond B [OR]
> RewriteCond C
> RewriteCond D
> ```

This is equivalent to `A and (B or C) and D`. Processing stops early if conditions are not met. So in this example if `A` fails then no further processing occurs.

> ```
> RewriteCond A
> RewriteCond B
> RewriteCond C [OR]
> RewriteCond D
> ```

And this is equivalent to `A and B and (C or D)`.

> How can I create the following logic: **(A and B) or (C and D)** with RewriteCond?

In a general sense, there are various methods to achieve this logic, depending on the intended action. On Apache 2.4 you can embed an Apache expression in the `RewriteCond` directive, so you can more literally do something like:

```
RewriteCond expr "A && B" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "C && D"
```

(Although this could even be combined into a single condition.)

Or, use an Apache `<If>` expression directly. For example:

```
<If "(A && B) || (C && D)">
    RewriteRule ^ something
</If>
```

On earlier versions of Apache you can make use of environment variables (to store the results of intermediary expressions) and/or *skip* rules depending on the outcome of earlier conditions.

For example:

```
# If "A and B" then env var is set and the next rule is skipped
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteRule ^ - [E:A_AND_B:1,S=1] 

# If "C and D" then env var is set
RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
RewriteRule ^ - [E:C_AND_D:1]

RewriteCond A_AND_B [OR]
RewriteCond C_AND_D
RewriteRule <do-this>
```

Although you don't need two env vars in the above - one will do:

```
# If "A and B" then env var is set and the next rule is skipped
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteRule ^ - [E:SUCCESS:1,S=1] 

# If "C and D" then env var is set
RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
RewriteRule ^ - [E:SUCCESS:1]

# If neither "A and B" or "C and D" is set then SUCCESS is also not set
RewriteCond SUCCESS
RewriteRule <do-this>
```

Or, *skip* and *chain* rules together (no env var required):

```
# If "A and B" then skip the next rule that checks "C and D"
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# If "C and D" then chain to the next rule
RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
RewriteRule ^ - [C]

# (A and B) or (C and D) - Otherwise this rule is skipped
RewriteRule <do-this>
```

However, depending on what you are doing you can also be creative with regex and "link" conditions together using backreferences to earlier conditions. For example, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69720906/369434) to the following question: [Apache mod_rewrite/mod_redirect: convert URL with query parameters into an SEO-friendly URL. some query parameters are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69716591/apache-mod-rewrite-mod-redirect-convert-url-with-query-parameters-into-an-seo-f)

Comment: What a great and thorough answer, thank you!

Comment: Syntax doesn't seem to be exactly correct as far as I can tell, but still this answer is still very helpful

Comment: @shaune The syntax is not meant to be "exactly correct". This is _pseudo-code_, as I stated at the top of my answer, to match the format the OP used in the question. The purpose here is to look at the bigger picture and explain the general _logic_, rather than getting bogged down in the specific syntax (which is not important here and would only confuse matters). `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` represent the general "expressions" which could evaluate to either _true_ or _false_. However, the syntax of those expressions will naturally vary depending on where (in which directive) they are being used.

Comment: @shaune If you found this answer "very helpful" then please consider upvoting it to help other readers and to show your appreciation. Thanks, much appreciated. :)